# Convert string to datetime now format

Tags: c#, string, datetime

How I can convert string 23:59 to datetime format?
So that I can reduce the current time in it.

Example: 
String = 23:59 minus
Datime.Now = 13.8.2014 10:59:55

Time left 12 hours 0 minutes.

Comment: `DateTime.Parse()`/`DateTime.ParsExact()`?

Comment: This question gets asked unreasonably often. Did you at least *try* searching first? Maybe the documentation? Maybe Stack Overflow? Maybe the entire Internet? Or maybe just the Intellisense listing?

Comment: I used the search, but I could not find a suitable answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i would use ParseExact

```
TimeSpan tsDifference = DateTime.ParseExact("23:59", "HH:mm", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) - DateTime.Now;
```

Answer (score 0):

use this :

```
DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(string);
System.TimeSpan diff= DateTime.Now.Subtract(date);
```

diff will contain your deffernce